# Whose idea was it to create this short-time ft tag?

Tags: discussion

why was that tag created?  why not just leave it as stft?

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/tags/short-time-ft/synonyms

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for pointing this out Robert!
It looks like I am the one to blame - totally don't remember that. Maybe it was a suggestion which I clicked on without even thinking.

I've merged the tags so now it's only `stft`.

Comment: thank you jojek

Comment: Neat for tag merger to be a thing

Answer (score 1):

That mapping has been there for (nearly) 5 years.

[image: Mapping info]